# text jumps up when fadedin or shown

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a simple sidebar that opens up when the user clicks the toggle button and when it's open I would like to show some text next to the icons.

However, when I open up the sidebar and try to `fadeIn()` or `show()` the text, it 'jumps' up and creates an undesired effect of expanding then deflating the sidebar while the sidebar itself is expanding.

Is there a way to make this text just appear next to icon instead of the jumping effect?

I assume it's because of timing but I'm not sure how I can resolve it and I'd rather not use `setTimeout()`;

https://jsfiddle.net/dqf8byn9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try showing the text only after the sidebar expanded. `animate()` can take a function to run when complete as argument. Try changing your code like so:

`$('.sidebar').animate({ width: '200px' }, 400, "swing", function(){
    $('span').removeClass('hidden');
});`

`400` and `"swing"` are the default values for duration and easing.

Comment: While this is one way to do it, my version allows the JavaScript to still stay almost the same (with minor changes just as the starting code wasn't perfect) as it uses 1 line of CSS to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `white-space:nowrap;` to the `.sidebar a` selector would fix the issue. It would also allow for you having the sidebar as wide, or narrow as you like.

This snippet shows the code working.

```js
$('.sidebar-toggle').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $('.sidebar').stop().animate({
      width: '50px'
    });
    $('span').stop().fadeOut();
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.sidebar').stop().animate({
      width: '200px'
    });
    $('span').stop().fadeIn();
  }
});
```

```css
.sidebar {
  width: 50px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  top: -1em;
  left: 1em;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
  <a class="sidebar-toggle">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />
    <span class="hidden">Test</span>
  </a>
  <a>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />
    <span class="hidden">Test</span>
  </a>
  <a>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />
    <span class="hidden">Test</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed it to 75px in the fiddle but if you run it a couple times you can see it still has the same problem. I would still like to keep the sidebar slim though so expanding it is not the best solution in my case.

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy I've also made the code work with fading in the text, to make the transition look slightly nice. I changed the colour of the background to make it easier to see what's happening

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy if you look at my updated code snippet, it works having the container as small as you like with the nice fade in affect on the text. Just adding white-space:nowrap; to the anchor tag works perfectly.